# Threading takes longer than non threaded program

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I'm working on the below code. The task is to generate 1,000,000 random numbers and save these to a .txt-file. The code I'm using without any threading needs about 2.5 seconds to run, but the threading version needs anywhere between 120 - 280 seconds. I have no clue where and why it goes wrong. Are the locks inhibiting each other?

**Simple version**

```
import random
import timeit
import os

start = timeit.default_timer()

f = open('file2.txt', 'a')

for i in range(0,1000000):
    f.write(str(random.randint(0,32576)))
    f.write('\n')
    
f.close()

end = timeit.default_timer()
```

**Threading version**

```
import threading
import queue
import random
import timeit
import os

tasks = queue.Queue()
start = timeit.default_timer()
output = open('file2.txt', 'w')
output_lock = threading.Lock()

def worker(thread_number):
    while not tasks.empty():
        tasks.get()
        f = open('file2.txt','a')
    

        with output_lock:  # block until lock is available
            f.write(str(random.randint(0,32767)))
            f.write('\n')
            f.close() 
        tasks.task_done()

for i in range(1000000):
    tasks.put(i)

for thread in range(8):
    threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(thread,)).start()

print('waiting')
tasks.join()
```

Comment: Your multi-threaded version opens and closes the output file one time for each number written. Your single-threaded version only opens it and closes it one time in all. If you fix that problem, then the multi-threaded version might be able to run almost as fast as the single threaded version.

Comment: In addition to what's already been stated about I/O, you could speed your code even further by using `f.write('/n'.join([str(random.randint(0,32576)) for i in range(0,1000000)]))`.

Comment: Problem 2: Your threads are all trying to write to the same file in the same file system. I don't know much about how that works inside some massive data center somewhere, but anywhere else (e.g., in desktop, laptop, or mobile computing) the I/O is going to be the bottleneck. Eight threads can't push the data out to the file any faster than a single thread can do.

Comment: Finally, before you try to use Python in particular for parallel processing, you might want to read this: https://realpython.com/python-gil/

Comment: @SolomonSlow: Yes, fixing the opening of the file helped a lot, thank you! Now the code needs "only" 17 seconds to run!